# How do I change the road width after using Blender OSM to import them?

Tags: faces, blender-osm

I have used blender-osm to import the streets but how do I make the roads wider? I have been looking in settings/profiles but can't find it..

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://github.com/vvoovv/blosm/wiki/Documentation#roads-and-paths

Comment: Yes, I have read it but I was unable to do it. I am not very familiar with blender so any tips are welcome.

Comment: It's a third-party addon anyway and not part of Blender so we can't really help.